# How should I initialize f:selectOneRadioButton component?

Tags: jsf, design-patterns, xhtml, software-design

I think this is low hanging fruit, but my coworkers and I have discussions daily of things such as this.

So I have multiple radio buttons on my view, around 10...

Should I initialize the radio button labels and values as a Map in the constructor directly, create an encapsulating method and call it from the constructor, build the list in the static initialization block, or should I hard code it in the view? There are many ways to accomplish the goal but I don’t know what is best practice

```
public RadioButtonBean(){
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
}
```

OR

```
public RadioButtonBean(){
    this.loadRadioButtonSelection();
}

private void loadRadioButtonSelection(){
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
    this.radioButtonSelection.put(“Age”,”Age”);
}
```

With the view

```
<f:selectOneRadioButton value=“#{radioButtonBean.selection}”>
     <f:selectItems value=“#{radioButtonBean.radioButtonSelection}”/>
 </f:selectOneRadioButton>
```

OR Just this

```
<f:selectOneRadioButton value=“#{radioButtonBean.selection}”>
     <f:selectItem value=“Age” label=“Age”/>
     <f:selectItem value=“Age” label=“Age”/>
     <f:selectItem value=“Age” label=“Age”/>
     <f:selectItem value=“Age” label=“Age”/>
     <f:selectItem value=“Age” label=“Age”/>
     <f:selectItem value=“Age” label=“Age”/>
     <f:selectItem value=“Age” label=“Age”/>
     <f:selectItem value=“Age” label=“Age”/>
     <f:selectItem value=“Age” label=“Age”/>
     <f:selectItem value=“Age” label=“Age”/>
 </f:selectOneRadioButton>
```

Comment: it would be great if you could post some code

Comment: It's always preferable to pick label from the property file if we need to support internationalization and localization. From where you are retrieving other Drop-down or Radio Buttons in your application?

Comment: Code has been added If this is confusing please let me know, I don’t post a lot on Stack.

Comment: Best practice totally depends on your usecase. Is it all static?  Only used in one place  or not (you can still use 'includes' or wrap the component or... all additional factors, as is I18N and more. Effectively making answering this question 'opinion based'...